# "Apply to" vs "apply for"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions, collocation, to-for

> 1. - Do I need to be registered before I can apply for university
>    - Do I need to be registered before I can apply to university
> 2. - Do I need to be registered before I can apply for my Bachelor of Education
>    - Do I need to be registered before I can apply to my Bachelor of Education
> 3. - When can I apply for my Bachelor of Education
>    - When can I apply to Bachelor of Education

Which preposition should I choose?

Comment: You apply *for* the thing you want, *to* the one(s) who can give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

[These answers apply to British/American English. Usage may be different in other dialects, e.g. Indian English.]

Generally, you apply *to* somewhere *for* something.

If you apply *for* university, 'university' is what you expect to receive. In this case 'university' is short for 'a university education', which is technically incorrect but is common usage.

'Apply to university' is correct form, but it implies 'apply to *a* university', i.e. that you expect the answer to be the same regardless of which university. More likely you would want to say 'Do I have to register to apply for [a specific university course]'

'Do I need to be registered before I can apply for my Bachelor of Education?' - This is correct.

'Do I need to be registered before we can apply to my Bachelor of Education?' - This is not correct. Your BoE is what you're applying *for*, not where you're applying *to*.